# Exception using mongodb as infinispan cache store

Tags: mongodb, infinispan, distributed-caching

I  want to use MongoDb as cacche store for the infinispan to persist the data evicted according to policy

i am posting the snippet of the code that is causing exception along with the exception

```
ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
MongoDBCacheStore strgBuilder = new MongoDBCacheStore();
ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
b.persistence()
 .addStore(MongoDBCacheStoreConfigurationBuilder.class)
 .host( "localhost" )
 .port( 27017 )
 .timeout( 1500 )
 .acknowledgment( 0 )
 .username( "" )
 .password( "" )
 .database( "infinispan_cachestore" )
 .collection( "entries" );
/* DefaultCacheManager manager=new DefaultCacheManager(b.build());
Cache ch=manager.getCache();
ch.put("username","sogani"); */

final Configuration configcache = b.build();
MongoDBCacheStoreConfiguration store = (MongoDBCacheStoreConfiguration) configcache.persistence().stores().get(0);
```

exception that I am getting is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.infinispan.loaders.mongodb.configuration.MongoDBCacheStoreConfigurationBuilder.
```

Any pointer will be of a great help
Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB was not updated after new persistence API was adopted in Infinispan. Try Infinispan 5.2.7.Final, maybe 5.3.0.Final or look into adaptor52x stuff. Or, even better, try to reimplement it using the new CacheWriter interface and issue a PR - the existing code should provide you some guidelines.