# Infinispan MongoDb CacheStore Exception

Tags: java, mongodb, infinispan

I want to use MongoDb as cachestore for Infinispan but getting following exception 
It is different form the question [Exception using mongodb as infinispan cache store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934135/exception-using-mongodb-as-infinispan-cache-store)
since the method b.loader() is not availabe in infinispan 7.0 jar i just figured out the turn around by using b.persistence.addStore() but still getting the exception as mentioned in the question
Code--

```
ConfigurationBuilder b = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    b.loaders().addStore(
    MongoDBCacheStoreConfigurationBuilder.class).host( "localhost" )
    .port( 27017 )
    .timeout( 1500 )
    .acknowledgment( 0 )
    .username( "mongoDBUSer" )
    .password( "mongoBDPassword" )

    .database( "infinispan_cachestore" )
    .collection( "entries" );

    final Configuration config = b.build();
    MongoDBCacheStoreConfiguration store = (MongoDBCacheStoreConfiguration) config.loaders().cacheLoaders().get(0);

    EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager=new DefaultCacheManager();
    cacheManager.defineConfiguration("usersCache", config);
    //DefaultCacheManager manger=new DefaultCacheManager(config);
    Cache<String, String> usersCache = cacheManager.getCache("usersCache");
```

Exception:--

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.start() on object of type CacheLoaderManagerImpl
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:207)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:889)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:658)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:647)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:550)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:221)
    at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:691)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:685)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:648)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:544)
    at com.infini.demo.DemoWithInfi5.main(DemoWithInfi5.java:31)
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to start cache loaders
    at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.start(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load null class!
    at org.infinispan.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:224)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.createCacheLoader(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:346)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.createCacheLoader(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.start(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:149)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: @user2106092 - Request you to please update the last question @ [Exception using mongodb as infinispan cache store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934135/exception-using-mongodb-as-infinispan-cache-store) (as per Neil's findings), instead of asking new questions every time for the same issue

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the question that was asked ,with the change in version of infinispan jar the method b.loader() was not availabe so i just figure out the tuen around and use b.persistence().addStore() and in both the cases the exception is different

Answer (score 0):

Download [infinispan-cachestore-mongodb-5.3.0.final.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/infinispan-cachestore-mongodb/infinispan-cachestore-mongodb-5.3.0.final.jar.zip) and import it into your project and be sure to import the package inside the class that uses it.

Comment: i am using the same version jar and it is in my class path

Comment: @user2106092 Have you imported it in your class that uses it?

Comment: yes i have used the appropriate imports